# Manual stack backtrace on Windows mobile (SEH)

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, arm, pocketpc

Following situation: I'm developing an windows mobile application using the sdk 6. Target machine is a nautiz x7. To improve the error reporting I want to catch the structured exceptions (SEH) and do a stack backtrace to store some information for analysis.

So far I have the information where the exception was thrown (windows core.dll) and I can backtrace the return adresses thru the stack.

But what I want to know is, which instruction in my code caused the exception?

Does anyone know how to use the available exception and context information to get the appropriate function/instruction address?

Unfortunately windows mobile 6 sdk for pocketpc does not support all the helper functions to do stackwalks or mini dumps.

Comment: Are you still interested in this? If so, can you please share where you got so far?

Comment: There is also [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047864/how-to-decode-a-windows-ce-call-stack). It might be the part you are missing.