# WinCE: How can I determine the module that contains a code address?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce

I wrote a solution that involved OpenProcess, EnumProcessModules, GetModuleInformation and GetModuleBaseName, but apparently EnumProcessModules and GetModuleBaseName do not exist in Windows CE! What alternative is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do this with CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, Module32First, Module32Next, Process32First and Process32Next. First you have to get a list of modules, then search through the list of modules to find the desired address.

```
#include <Tlhelp32.h>

struct MyModuleInfo
{
    BYTE* Base;
    HMODULE Handle;
    DWORD Size;
    enum { MaxNameLen = 36 };
    TCHAR Name[MaxNameLen];
};

bool GetModuleList(vector<MyModuleInfo>& moduleList)
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_GETALLMODS, 0);
    if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    MODULEENTRY32 moduleInfo;
    moduleInfo.dwSize = sizeof(moduleInfo);
    if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &moduleInfo)) do {
        MyModuleInfo myInfo;
        myInfo.Handle = moduleInfo.hModule;
        myInfo.Base = moduleInfo.modBaseAddr;
        myInfo.Size = moduleInfo.modBaseSize;
        memcpy(myInfo.Name, moduleInfo.szModule, min(sizeof(myInfo.Name), sizeof(moduleInfo.szModule)));
        myInfo.Name[myInfo.MaxNameLen-1] = '\0';
        moduleList.push_back(myInfo);
    } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &moduleInfo));

    // The module list obtained above only contains DLLs! To get the EXE files
    // also, we must call Process32First and Process32Next in a loop.
    PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
    processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);
    if (Process32First(hSnapshot, &processInfo)) do {
        MyModuleInfo myInfo;
        myInfo.Handle = NULL; // No handle given
        myInfo.Base = (BYTE*)processInfo.th32MemoryBase;
        myInfo.Size = 0x800000; // No size provided! Allow max 8 MB
        memcpy(myInfo.Name, processInfo.szExeFile, min(sizeof(myInfo.Name), sizeof(processInfo.szExeFile)));
        myInfo.Name[myInfo.MaxNameLen-1] = '\0';
        moduleList.push_back(myInfo);
    } while(Process32Next(hSnapshot, &processInfo));

    // Debug output
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)moduleList.size(); i++) {
        MyModuleInfo& m = moduleList[i];
        TRACE(_T("%-30s: 0x%08x - 0x%08x\n"), m.Name, (DWORD)m.Base, (DWORD)m.Base + m.Size);
    }

    CloseToolhelp32Snapshot(hSnapshot);
    return true;
}

const MyModuleInfo* GetModuleForAddress(vector<MyModuleInfo>& moduleList, void* address)
{
    for (int m = 0; m < (int)moduleList.size(); m++) {
        const MyModuleInfo& mInfo = moduleList[m];
        if (address >= mInfo.Base && address < mInfo.Base + mInfo.Size)
            return &mInfo;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```